# ¿Como se editan las rutas en ionic 5?

Tags: ionic

estoy recién utilizando ionic y he creado un proyecto nuevo con las **tabs** que vienen por defecto, por lo que como pagina de inicio queda **/tabs/tab1**.
He añadido más paginas como un **index**, **home** y un **login**, pero no se como hacer para que la pagina principal ahora sea **/index** y no **/tabs** que debería venir después de hacer un login.

Intenté editar el archivo **app-routing.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { PreloadAllModules, RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    loadChildren: () => import('./tabs/tabs.module').then(m => m.TabsPageModule)
  },
  {
    path: 'home',
    loadChildren: () => import('./home/home.module').then( m => m.HomePageModule)
  },
  {
    path: 'index',
    loadChildren: () => import('./index/index.module').then( m => m.IndexPageModule)
  }
];
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { preloadingStrategy: PreloadAllModules })
  ],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule {}
```

Moviendo **index** al primer lugar y dejando **path** vacío, pero al hacerlo las demás paginas no cargan, queda todo en blanco.

Answer (score 1):

La pagina inicial es la que tenga el path vacio, que en este caso es la que lleva a tabs, si quieres que envie primero a index, ponle un path a tabs y quita el de index:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { PreloadAllModules, RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'tabs',
    loadChildren: () => import('./tabs/tabs.module').then(m => m.TabsPageModule)
  },
  {
    path: 'home',
    loadChildren: () => import('./home/home.module').then( m => m.HomePageModule)
  },
  {
    path: '',
    loadChildren: () => import('./index/index.module').then( m => m.IndexPageModule)
  }
];
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { preloadingStrategy: PreloadAllModules })
  ],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule {}
```

Esto te debería de funcionar

Comment: Sí lo intenté y funciona, pero las demás páginas quedan en blanco